# Pedido com Checkbox + inputys

Tags: php, html

Galera, como ficaria p/ fazer um mini sistema de pedidos, atraves do checkbox e input, essa seria a ideia no código abaixo:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="produto[]" value="Feijao">Feijao - Quantidade
    <input type="number" name="qtd[]" min="0" max="99">


    <input type="checkbox" name="produto[]" value="Arroz">Arroz - Quantidade
    <input type="number" name="qtd[]" min="0" max="99">

    <input type="submit" name="">
</form>
```

como faria p/ pegar esses itens atraves do php? a ideia seria: Quantidade e o produto marcado ao lado - Ex:

```
2 - Feijão
3 - Arroz
```

Comment: O problema é obter os valores usando o $_POST do PHP?

Comment: Sim amigo......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Formulário** use índices nos names dos inputs

para feijão: `name="produto[0]"` `name="qtd[0]"`

para arroz: `name="produto[1]"` `name="qtd[1]"`

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="produto[0]" value="Feijao">Feijao - Quantidade
    <input type="number" name="qtd[0]" min="0" max="99">


    <input type="checkbox" name="produto[1]" value="Arroz">Arroz - Quantidade
    <input type="number" name="qtd[1]" min="0" max="99">


    <input type="submit" name="enviar">
</form>
```

**PHP**

1. Sem loop

   ```
   if (isset($_POST['enviar'])){
       $feijao = $_POST['produto']['0'];
       $qtdfeijao = $_POST['qtd']['0'];
       $arroz = $_POST['produto']['1'];
       $qtdarroz = $_POST['qtd']['1'];

       if($feijao!="" && $qtdfeijao!=""){
           echo $qtdfeijao." - ".$feijao;
       }

       echo "<br>";

       if($arroz!="" && $qtdarroz!=""){
           echo $qtdarroz." - ".$arroz;
       }
   }
   ```
2. com loop

   ```
   if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
       // quantidade de checkboxes 2
       for ($i=0;$i<2;$i++) {
           $Prod = $_POST['produto'][$i];
           $Quant = $_POST['qtd'][$i]; 
           if ($Prod!="" && $Quant!=""){
               echo $Quant.' - '.$Prod.'<br />';   
           }
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Irmão está funcionando quase 100%, porém quando seleciono apenas o arroz, dar erro =/

Comment: Parabéns amigo, é isso mesmo...Brigadão pela força!